# Cleaning up text, from ALLCAPS to <em>allcaps</em>

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to clean up some text for html that used ALLCAPS instead of italics. So I'd like to take something that looks like this:

```
Here is an artificial EXAMPLE of a piece of TEXT that
uses allcaps as a way of EMPHASIZING words.
```

And convert it into this:

```
Here is an artificial <em>example</em> of a piece of <em>text</em> that
uses allcaps as a way of <em>emphasizing</em> words.
```

I'm tagging this with regex and notepad++, but (as you can probably tell) I don't know the first thing about how to use them. Any alternative techniques for a novice like myself would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting non-ASCII letters, like `ÄRGERLICH`, too? How about words containing punctuation like `DON'T`?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: No to both. Just ordinary A-Z letters without any punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using this regex:

```
([A-Z][A-Z']+)
```

This will match any words with upper case letters including punctuation such as those in words like `DON'T`.

Note: This won't match non-ASCII letters.

---

To use this in Notepad++:

Click CTRL+H to get to the Replace dialog, then put in:

- Find what: `([A-Z][A-Z']+)`
- Replace with: `<em>\1</em>`
- Match case: *Checked*
- Search mode: *Regular expression*

Try a "Find next" first to see if the expression matches what you expect.

Comment: It could be `\p{lu}` in Perl, except that Notepad++ doesn't seem to support this syntax.

Comment: GlitchMr, Notepad++'s regex support doesn't even cover regular languages. You can't really expect any features from it ...

Comment: @ohaal: Your suggestion seems to replace EXAMPLE with <em>EXAMPLE</em>. But I'm wanting to replace EXAMPLE with <em>example</em>.

Comment: Since this is presumably for display in HTML, you can force the italicized text to appear in lowercase by using the CSS property `text-transform:lowercase`.